# Are there any commonly used implementations of IQueryable?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm writing a unit test of a class. Several of the class's methods take `IQueryable` objects as parameters, and I want to mock the objects that are passed into those methods. Are there any collections built into C# that implement `IQueryable`? If not, how can I mock these objects?

Comment: You should only implement your own `IQueryable` if you have a specialized requirement for a provider, etc. Otherwise, John Saunders answer is the best option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `IEnumerable<T>.AsQueryable()`. Use whatever `IEnumerable<T>` implementer you like.